# How can i print a star patterns using angularjs(can i use ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<span name="hover-star" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="red-tooltip" data-html="true" title="<div class='row' style='font-size:10px; color:blue; '><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star col-sm-1' style='width:3%'></span>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star col-sm-1' style='width:3%'></span>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star col-sm-1' style='width:3%'></span>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star col-sm-1' style='width:3%'></span>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star col-sm-1' style='width:3%'></span>
```

The above code i have used in HTML to print the pattern as * * * * * in a tooltip

i have used the jquery callbyname in my .js file
 $('span[name="hover-star"]').tooltip(); for tooltip functionality

Now,i want to include the pattern * ** *** **** ***** in my tooltip using angularjs ng-repeat directive(i have read in a document it works as for loop).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following by using nested `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="i in getNumberPattern(numberPattern) track by $index" style="display:inline;">
  <span ng-repeat="i in getNumberPattern($index) track by $index">*</span>
</div>
```

Check out the 
[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XautNKYjEfLiosCWDDVP?p=preview)

In the answer I have simply displayed character `*`, add your own styling to display the icons.